# Huge size simple feature

Tags: r, r-sf

Dear stack overflow community,
this is my first question on this website. I am using R and try to merge two shapefiles using `sf::st_union`. However, although the shapefiles do not take that much space, the union is quite heavy!

Here is a minimum working example with the sizes from my terminal:

```
library(sf)

canada <- st_read("./gpr_000b11a_e.shp", quiet = TRUE)
usa <- st_read("./cb_2017_us_state_500k.shp", quiet = TRUE)

usa <- st_transform(x = usa, crs = st_crs(canada))

north_america = st_union(usa, canada)
```

And the size of the three objects:

```
print(object.size(canada), units = "auto")
58.9 Mb

print(object.size(usa), units = "auto")
4.6 Mb

print(object.size(north_america), units = "auto")
3 Gb
```

Do you have any idea of what is happening and how I could get something lighter? Also, all I want is the geometry, but `sf::st_geometry` did not make the object smaller.

Comment: It's possible the border doesn't line up precisely, so it's calculating lots of tiny holes. Starting with data that contains both countries (maybe from [rnaturalearth](https://github.com/ropensci/rnaturalearth)) may help. Or add a tiny buffer first.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks, I chose rnaturalearth for now. ```sf::st_buffer``` is running from yesterday evening and is still not done, so I might give up

Comment: It really shouldn't take that long. Maybe if you're using super high-res maps on a very low-powered machine, I guess. Maybe try it with really low-res versions first to make sure it's doing what you want? Not perfect, obviously, but it's a relatively quick way to check your code.

Answer (score 0):

Will using rbind provide what you are after?
here is a link to sf help for rbind
https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/bind.html

```
north_america = rbind(usa, canada)
```